# Unable to use angular-summernote summarnote function undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, summernote

I am using Summernote Angular directive. However, for some reason it is not working.

Problem:

It is unable to identify the summarnote function...

[image]

```
<summernote code="text"></summernote>

<script src="components/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="components/bower_components/angular-summernote/src/angular-summernote.js"></script>

ypeError: undefined is not a function
    at activate (http://localhost/tm/app/components/bower_components/angular-summernote/src/angular-summernote.js:57:15)
    at link (http://localhost/tm/app/components/bower_components/angular-summernote/src/angular-summernote.js:129:30)
    at http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:7113:44
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:6711:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:6105:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:6108:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:6705:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:6105:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular.js:6001:30)
    at link (http://localhost/tm/Scripts/angular-route.js:918:7) <div class="summernote ng-isolate-scope" code="text"> angular.js:10071
```

The directive that I am currently using is: https://github.com/outsideris/angular-summernote/blob/master/src/angular-summernote.js

Can you suggest any better alternative if this is not the right solution.

I have also tried with:

```
<script src="components/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="components/bower_components/angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/n8dt4/light/

Comment: I've encountered the same exact problem right now- I've used bower install summernote and bower install angular-summernote

Comment: Thank you. I did saw this link and yes it is working but not my code. I am not using any fancy except that it is in the controller that is route from index.html. I have included angular-summernote and summer-note jquery. These examples does not give a complete picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me, it might work for you too:

change:

```
<script src="components/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="components/bower_components/angular-summernote/src/angular-summernote.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="components/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="components/bower_components/angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.min.js">
```

The exact flow was running:

```
bower install summernote
bower install angular-summernote
```

and then:

```
<script src="components/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="components/bower_components/angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.min.js">
```

Comment: No luck mate it is not working. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @codebased are you sure? I've had the same exact problem and it was solved. If you're using grunt serve try to re-run it.

Comment: ok mate it is done . problem was that jquery inclusion was after angular. I will include the my answer below too.

Answer (score 3):

You must include jquery and bootstrap such like:

```
<script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

refer [a example](https://github.com/outsideris/angular-summernote/blob/master/examples/index.html). 
It's [summernote's dependencies](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html#installation)

And I'm angular-summernote author.

Comment: I definitely had the jquery before bootstrap and still encountered the same error message.

Comment: Now I read @codebased 's comments. It looks jquery dependency problem. The error message is caused by jquery dependency.